# syntax of select statement vb.net

Tags: mysql

I have master table channels which has all channels(this big table have all channels)
I have another table user_channel which only has this user channels(only this user channels)

I need to get all channels from (table channels) that does not  exsits in this specific user channel list.

I tried this but useless:

```
SELECT channel from channels where NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT channel FROM user_channels  WHERE  
User_channel.user_name=’& Me.DataGridView_user_update.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString &’” And    
channels.channel_name = user_channels.channel_name )
```

Comment: I believe you're missing a *double quote* sign before the first *ampersand*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your question is not clear enough to be answered correctly!
- Use the `primary key column` of table `channels` in table `user_channels`, so instead of `user_channels.channel_name` you should have `user_channels.primaryKeyColumnOfTableChannels`

Now I think below should work for you:

```
SELECT channel from channels where NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT channel FROM user_channels  WHERE  
User_channel.user_name='" & Me.DataGridView_user_update.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString &”' )
```